# The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

When I run the "C:\Program Files***\sencha" app upgrade command I get the below result. How can I upgrade my Sencha app?

```
Sencha Cmd v6.6.0.13
[ERR] Cannot satisfy requirements for "ext"!
[ERR]    The following versions cannot be satisfied:
[ERR]       root: ext@6.5.0.775 (No matches!)
[ERR] Cannot resolve package requirements
[ERR]
[ERR] The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (6.5.2
.15).
[ERR] Running "sencha app upgrade" may resolve the error described above.
[ERR]
```